# Overwrite overflow:hidden from LayoutPanel's Layer

Tags: css, gwt, widget, layoutpanels

is there any way to overwrite overflow:hidden from LayoutPanel's Layer?
This is what I have:

```
   <g:LayoutPanel>  
    <g:layer height="20px" bottom="0px" right="0px" width="70px" style="overflow:visible;">
    <g:Anchor styleName="{style.helpLink}" ui:field="helpL">Help</g:Anchor>
    </g:layer>
   </g:LayoutPanel>
```

I could not assign ui:field to layer element, and inline style above is apparently not working.
I need to assign overflow:visible to that particular layer. Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to get down to the DOM level.

You can do: `helpL.getElement().getParentElement().getStyle().setOverflow( Overflow.VISIBLE );` after your widget loads.